# How to access Azure Key Vault Using SSIS Script Task?

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-keyvault, ssis-2012, script-task

Need to access Azure Key Vault using SSIS Script Task in C#, to assign the Azure SQL Connection String to Connection Manager in SSIS.

Comment: This is a horrible mix of on prem and cloud technologies. This is a guide to the KV REST API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/secrets/get-secret/get-secret and this is a guide to calling web API's from SSIS https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-consume-web-api-through-ssis-package/

Answer (score 0):

To Achieve the above requirements , You may refer the below workaround.

- Create an application ASP.NET MVC application.
- Create ***Azure keyvault secret*** for the database connection string. And give permission to your app from *Key Vault->Access Policy*.
- In  application level use the Connected Service to access the K*ey Vault-> Secret for connection string* , Which added in the code in `webconfig` and added `nuget packages` then test in your local and then deploy to Azure.

For example:

`web.config`

```
<configSections><section name="configBuilders" 
  type="System.Configuration.ConfigurationBuildersSection, 
  System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
 PublicKeyToken=b0xxxxxxx3a" 
 restartOnExternalChanges="false" 
 requirePermission="false" />
<builders>
 <add name="AzureKeyVault" vaultName="Prod-ConSt-01"type"  Microsoft 
.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.AzureKeyVaultConfigBuilder,
 Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.Azure, 
Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
 PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxx"
 vaultUri="https://mywebsite-prod-const-01.vault.azure.net/" />< 
/builders>
</configBuilders>

<connectionStrings configBuilders="AzureKeyVault">
 <add name="ProductionConnstr" connectionString="from key vault" 
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

For more information please refer the below links:-

- ***MICROSFT DOCUMENTATION:*** [***Use a managed identity to connect Key Vault to an Azure web app in .NET***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/tutorial-net-create-vault-azure-web-app)
- ***SO THREAD:*** [***Not able to get Azure Key-Vault working in app when deployed to Azure***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70808077/not-able-to-get-azure-key-vault-working-in-app-when-deployed-to-azure) & [***Azure SDK with SSIS***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71164425/azure-sdk-with-ssis)

Comment: Thanks Ajay for inputs. But its looks like we are connecting the AKV from Web APP, but I am trying to connect the AKV from SSIS Script Task.

Comment: Could you please refer this [Blog](https://nishantrana.me/2020/11/27/read-secret-from-azure-key-vault-using-secretclient-class-console-app-c/)